# PHP not rendering on customers server correctly. Broke at -> for DB query. Images Included

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Odd problem, let me try and explain it clearly.

I wrote a WordPress plugin, and it's been installed on dozens of servers without issue. A client tried to install it today, and they received the following error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /sitepathhere/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/insert.php on line 302`

The function was outputting text via an echo rather than returning text. Fine, I changed it to return the text and all worked ok for that part. Then the admin panel and front end of wordpress were displaying my PHP code from the plugin, starting at seemingly random parts. Here you can see a screen shot of the source code of a page:

[image]

Even when I combine the code into a single file, which requires no "includes" of the insert.php file, the page still shows all my PHP code in the header and doesn't process fully.

[image]

Any idea why the server can't process my Plugin? The code in the second screenshot is mis-formatted and it's not that way in the actual file.

Comment: The images don't even exist anymore...

Comment: Yes, the answer was given, and the images removed as they contained some identifying information of the server. Sorry.

Comment: You should put them back up, but with blurred images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like "short_open_tag" is not enabled on that server.

Just replace

```
<?
```

to

```
<?php
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: That's probably it! Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: @Branndon: As a rule short tags are generally frowned upon in PHP, get used to not using them, they are often disabled.